# Need to understand the difference between calling JavaScript Remoting in two different ways

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

Can someone explain what is the difference between calling JavaScript Remoting in two different ways -

One way is mentioned @ https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_namespaces.htm

Another way is mentioned @ https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_remote_method_inheritance.htm